# not able to call jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I understand this question might be the same. I have googled, unfortunately i might have have missed something similar. I apologies for the same.

I have created a dynamic table in js based on some json response and updated the table accordingly. Now i have a submit button which posts currently selected raw data as an ajax call. But i am unable to call jquery.
Following are the codes :

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ajax-button').click(function() {
    var formData=$("#careers").serialize();
    console.log("This is the skills : "+formData);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "currentopening",
            //data : "skills="+skills,
            data:formData,
            dataType : "json",
            async: true,
            success : function(response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);

                console.log("length of json response : "+obj.length)
                if(obj.length>0){
                //for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
                //{
                    console.log("the characteristics : "+obj[0].title);
                    addRow(obj);
                //}
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("dynamictable").innerHTML="No jobs found!";
                }
            }
        });
    });


});function addRow(obj) {

var table_1 = document.getElementById("dynamictable");

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){

var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.id="apply-button";

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("id",obj[i].jobID);
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "jobID");
input.setAttribute("value", obj[i].jobID);

var rowCount = table_1.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

var row1 = table_1.insertRow(rowCount);
row1.id="x";

var cell0=row1.insertCell(0);
var cell1=row1.insertCell(1);
var cell2=row1.insertCell(2);
var cell3=row1.insertCell(3);
var cell4=row1.insertCell(4);
var cell5=row1.insertCell(5);
var cell6=row1.insertCell(6);
var cell7=row1.insertCell(7);
var cell8=row1.insertCell(8);
var cell9=row1.insertCell(9);

cell0.headers="title"; cell1.headers="qualification"; cell2.headers="salary"; cell3.headers="companyName"; cell4.headers="tags"; cell5.headers="location"; 
cell6.headers="experience"; cell7.headers="aboutCompany";cell8.id="hidden-element";
cell9.id="doit";

cell0.innerHTML= obj[i].title;
cell1.innerHTML= obj[i].qualification;
cell2.innerHTML= obj[i].salary;
cell3.innerHTML= obj[i].companyName;
cell4.innerHTML= obj[i].tags;
cell5.innerHTML= obj[i].location;
cell6.innerHTML= obj[i].experience;
cell7.innerHTML= obj[i].aboutCompany;
document.getElementById("doit").appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("hidden-element").appendChild(input);}};$('#apply-button').click(function() {
console.log("id of current element : ");
    var formData=document.getElementById(this);
    console.log("id of current element : "+formData);
    //console.log("This is the filter : "+formData);
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "apply",
            //data : "skills="+skills,
            data:"jobID="+formData,
            dataType : "text",
            async: true,
            success : function(response) {console.log("The response : "+response);

            }
        });
    });
```

I suspect that since id **apply-button** is created dynamically and it is not under **document.load**  function, my button is not able to work.Please let me know if more information is required.

I would appreciate a response on this.

Comment: Are you getiing an error? If so, please post here

Comment: Hi Oliver, No errors, the page gets reloaded.

Comment: Please post the whole file here

Comment: Whole js file is posted above..and this js file is added in the last part of html...apologies not able to post html

Comment: Are you including jQuery before you include the above script?

Comment: yes before including the above script

Comment: since apply-button is created dynamically, you should do an event delegation instead of binding.  $(document).on('click','#apply-button',function() {

Comment: @DinoMyte Thank you for pointing that out. Many people do not know about event delegation in jQuery and get messed up on this type of thing. The fact still remains that the OP needs to cancel the default form submit, though. I have included your comment in my answer.

Comment: @Oliver Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).on("click", "#ajax-button", function (event) {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This stops the form from submitting, which is the default action on a submit button on a form, and it's why your page is getting refreshed.

## Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, since the form is being dynamically generated, you will need a delegator, not a binding. Above code has been revised.

Comment: OR, he could just return false.

Comment: That is acceptable as well. I think event.preventDefault() is a little more explicit, and I see it more often than not, but it really comes down to a matter of preference - they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try

```
$().click(){
    return false;
}
```

Stop execution of post back